# Etiquette for email introductions

Tags: email

I made a referral via email to a recruiter at my company. The recruiter asked me to introduce him and the referee via email, and to ask the referee to include a resume.

What exactly is the correct way to go about this? I can think of two.

1. Send both a single email:

   X and Y,
   X meet Y, Y is interested in interviewing you, please include a resume in your response.
2. Email only the referee

   Hi X,
   Here is the contact info of Y, he would like you to include a resume in your response to him.

Comment: You could also send both of them the same mail, possibly with the referee as the primary target while keeping the recruiter in cc.

Comment: @Llewellyn This is my thought exactly. A little like: To...Bob; CC...John Smith; Body... "Bob, I'd like to introduce you to John Smith, a recruiter I've referred you to who will be handling blah blah blah. I've included his contact information below. Please send a resume over to John. Sincerely, Guy." (assuming after email 1 you'll be cut out of the interaction).

Comment: @Llewellyn, I upvoted your comment, but I would vote for your answer, too, if you posted it as one.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to send a personal email to both of them and talk to them both as though they're in the same room.  Do a lot of "encouraging" in that "I would encourage you to call him as I feel that he may be what you're looking for" or words to that effect.  I'd include the number and contact information of the person you're introducing in the body of the email as well.

That's really all there is too it. Just say some nice things about each one so it sounds like you're introducing 2 friends. After that, it's all up to them.

Comment: Fair, although the toughest part is getting the phrasing correct. It feels foreign to write "X let me introduce you to Y" in an email. Could you update your answer with an example, and I will mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

To: Sue
Cc: Bob

Sue, there is a recruiter (here copied) interested in your resume.  Feel free to contact Bob directly if you're interested or have any questions.

Cheers & good luck,

Mikey